# PHP predefined variable storing Url

Tags: php, predefined-variables, current-page

Even if they are quite different I'm going to compare to php predefined variables:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

- the first is giving me the 'previous page'  including the GET parameters (Ex. mypage.php?**id=1**)
- the second one is returning let's say the 'barebone' structure of the url (Ex.mypage.php)

**IS THERE ANY WAY I CAN STORE THE CURRENT PAGE PLUS THE GET PARAMETERS?**

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.